# 2 actions en un mismo form en html

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

mi caso es el siguiente, tengo 1 script php donde en un login doy acceso a un usuario, y tengo otro script php donde doy acceso al administrador. ¿Cómo podría hacer para añadir dos actions en un mismo form, es decir, que un botón me haga dos funciones de actions?.

Estos serían mis 2 php que me gustaría poner para que me ejecutase el mismo action:

conexion.php:

```html
<?php
// Conexión con la base de datos
$link= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","entradata");
$usu=$_POST['usuario'];
$pwd=$_POST['contrasenya'];


$sql = "select * from usuarios where usuario='$usu' and contrasenya='$pwd' and rol_id=1";
$resultado = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)!=0)
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['nombre']=$usu;
$_SESSION['rol_id']=1;
$_SESSION['autentificado'] = "OK";
header ("Location: miperfil.php");
}
else {
header ("Location: Acceso.html");
}

mysql_free_result($resultado);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

conexion_admin.php:

```html
<?php
// Conexión con la base de datos
$link= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","entradata");
$usu=$_POST['usuario'];
$pwd=$_POST['contrasenya'];


$sql = "select * from usuarios where usuario='$usu' and contrasenya='$pwd' and rol_id=2";
$resultado = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)!=0)
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['nombre']=$usu;
$_SESSION['rol_id']=2;
$_SESSION['autentificado'] = "OK";
header ("Location: miperfiladmin.php");
}
else {
header ("Location: Acceso.html");
}

mysql_free_result($resultado);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Donde conexion.php es para que me redireccione a un perfil de un usuario normal, y conexion_admin.php es para que me redireccione al perfil del admin.

Este sería mi login con el botón donde me gustaría que el mismo botón cumpliese las dos funciones anteriores:

```html
    <section id="contacto">
        <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="conexion.php">  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 topmargin-sm">
                    <h3>Iniciar sesión:</h3>
                    <p>Si eres nuevo en Entradata, puedes registrarte <a href="Registro.html">aquí</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 topmargin-sm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="contrasenya" placeholder="Contraseña">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Acceso">Aceptar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respuesta corta: **Utiliza frontend con AJAX**

### ¿Qué es frontend?

Frontend es el lado del cliente, para resumir es lo que se pinta en pantalla. En frontend tenemos a HTML, CSS y JS

### ¿Qué es backend?

Backend es el lado del servidor, donde normalmente se hacen las APIs que serán consumidas por el frontend.

**AJAX** es la manera de enviar y recibir datos del servidor sin la necesidad de recargar la página.

### Solución

Quita el atributo `action` de la forma, tampoco necesitaremos un método.

```
<form id="mainForm">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 topmargin-sm">
         <h3>Iniciar sesión:</h3>
         <p>Si eres nuevo en Entradata, puedes registrarte <a href="Registro.html">aquí</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 topmargin-sm">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="Usuario">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <p>Iniciar sesión como:</p>
               <select id="loginAs" class="form-control">
                  <option value="admin">Administrador</option>
                  <option value="user">Usuario</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Acceso">Aceptar</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Debes usar JavaScript para hacer llamadas AJAX, hay dos formas de hacer esto:

- [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)
- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)

En este caso, voy a usar XMLHttpRequest, pero si gustas puedes revisar la referencia de fetch()

```
mainForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevenir que la página se recargue
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (loginAs.value == "admin") {
                xhr.open("POST", "conexion_admin.php");
            } else {
                xhr.open("POST", "conexion.php");
            }
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status <= 299 && xhr.status >= 200) {
                        // Petición enviada con éxito.
                        console.log(xhr.responseText); // Obtenemos la respuesta del backend
                    } else {
                        // Error en la petición
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send(`usuario=${user.value}&contrasenya=${pass.value}&Acceso=1`);
        }
```

**Explicación por encima de XHR (XmlHttpRequest)**

`xhr.open()` Abre la petición, tienes que especificar el tipo de método [(Documentación de métodos)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) seguido de la URL o archivo hacia donde se enviará le petición.

La petición XHR tiene 4 tipos de readyState diferentes

- 1 => OPENED (La petición se ha abierto)
- 2 => HEADERS_RECEIVED (Los encabezados del archivo backend se han recibido)
- 3 => LOADING (La petición se está enviando, está cargando la respuesta del backend)
- 4 => DONE (La operación se ha completado con éxito)

`xhr.send()` envía la petición, si vas a enviar información con POST, deberás poner esta información como tipo GET en parámetro

**Tip:** Los elementos HTML con un ID único se convierten en objetos de javascript, ejemplo:

`<div id="abc"></div>`

Esto será una constante llamada abc en javascript

`abc.innerHTML = "Hola Mundo";`

### EDIT

Utiliza el siguiente código para poner los datos en pantalla

Crea un div o cualquier elemento con un ID específico

HTML

```
<div id="ajaxResult"></div>
```

Añade ese div donde quieras que se muestre el resultado de la petición

Javascript (JS)

```
mainForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevenir que la página se recargue
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (loginAs.value == "admin") {
                xhr.open("POST", "conexion_admin.php");
            } else {
                xhr.open("POST", "conexion.php");
            }
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status <= 299 && xhr.status >= 200) {
                        // Petición enviada con éxito.
                        ajaxResult.innerHTML = xhr.responseText; // Obtenemos la respuesta del backend
                    } else {
                        // Error en la petición
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send(`usuario=${user.value}&contrasenya=${pass.value}&Acceso=1`);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Y el apartado XMLHttpRequest sería un archivo aparte como los php conexión?, ¿o lo añadiría en el mismo html que he insertado?

Comment: El XHR es una solución de javascript, puedes ponerlo en un archivo aparte y después vincularlo en tu HTML o puedes ponerlo en tu mismo archivo HTML si gustas

Comment: Por último, ¿este archivo tendría una extensión .xhr ,verdad?. Muchas gracias por tu contestación.

Comment: No, tendría una extensión .JS y luego vincula el archivo a tu HTML con `<script src="nombreArchivo.js"></script>` Debes poner el script al final de la etiqueta body para que javascript pueda ejecutarse sin fallos

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por tus contestaciones.

Comment: Una última cosa, si el backend envía respuesta, puedes verla en la consola; presiona CTRL + Shift + J (Windows) o Ctrl + Option + J (Mac)

Comment: Perfecto, ¿si el código XHR quiero meterlo dentro del HTML, donde lo podría poner?

Comment: Para mostrarlo en HTML, crea un div con un ID único (atributo HTML), luego ubica la línea que dice `console.log` y bórrala, en su reemplazo pon `nombreId.innerHTML = xhr.response` cambia nombreId con el id que le hayas puesto al div.

Comment: El problema es que no tengo esa línea de console.log para reemplazarlo. Lo siento por extenderme, pero esto me resulta nuevo y voy un poco perdido jajaja

Comment: Te estoy dejando un edit en unos momentos, utiliza ese código.

Comment: Perfecto, ahora me ha quedado mucho más claro. Muchas gracias